# Aligning a picture to bottom right in browser window

Tags: html

Im trying to markup a picture to show on the bottom right corner of the webpage.

If i set the overall width of the page to 100%
and i set the picture to float right at the bottom it makes the trick perfectly but above
the mentioned picture is a bigger width picture which is around 1600px so when you open the the page in the small window browser then the floated picture is aligned but the scrollbar apears and scrolls to the full width of the page without the floated picture..

```
body{width:100%;}
thepicture{width: 1289px;
height: 446px;
position:relative;
float:right;}
```

So the second aproach: to make the body or a wrapper div fix width that is bigger than the upper picture mentioned:

> body{min-width:1600px;}

Than looks great until somebody has a bigger screen than 1600px... the float ends at 1600px;

The firs solution needs to be tweaked but i cant figure it out how, some responsive floating would be great jquery maybe?
thanks in forwards

The problem is the pearl:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated**

May be this work:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
    min-width: 1648px; /* the width of the longest element */
}

#bottomwrap {
    /* replace with your background color */
    background: url(path/to/picture) bottom right no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Rememer to reset `body` `margin`, `padding` to zero and set `body` `height` to 100%

**Update:**

I have update the solution for your case, modify the HTML structure, you can review here http://jsbin.com/ulatis/1/edit

Comment: So use the background for the `#bottomwrap` div, set its `witdh` to 100% keep its width always equals to the width of the `body` element.

Comment: yes this was one of my first solutions but here the problem was that i would like this pic to go underneath the text above it (updated the link)

Comment: updated again, it seams to do the trick but i pulled back the picture and maximized the body height top:-189 is an ugly solution from me:)

Comment: I have update my solution, just modify the HTML a bit :) you can test use the link in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to use a background image here. Put the background on a 100% width div and set the background position to `right bottom`.

```
div.background{background: url('images/bg.png') no-repeat right bottom; width: 100%}
```

Comment: This really should work and its how many sites do it.  Do you have a link to your site?

Comment: Tested in your site and update my answer. Try `background` and `min-width`.

Comment: The CSS on your bottom div is correct.  The problem is that the `body` element isnt expanding to the browser width.  This is being caused by the first image element inside the main div.

Answer (score 0):

Try `position: fixed; z-index: -1;`, it does exactly what you're looking for.  [Example](https://tinker.io/f2f3e/1)

Comment: Been there, done that to, the problem is when i use that the picture floats over some of the page content when you resize the browser just like in your example